# How to install autokey in the home directory in linux?

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux

I am on a computer where I do not have admin rights. I can only install applications in the home directory.

Can someone provide a step by step guide on installing autokey in the home directory in archlinux?

Comment: I edited your question, if you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit it again.

Answer (score 2):

One usual way is to:

1. Download source http://code.google.com/p/autokey/downloads/list
2. Extract it
3. Run something similar to `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`

Comment: When I run the command you mentioned, I get `./configure: Command not found.`